# How can I prevent 1 pixel line between background and gradient?

Tags: css, background, linear-gradients

[image: picture of problem]

When zooming, this line appears between the block and the gradient background. How an I get rid of the line? Specifically, noticed in Safari (After zooming a couple times, Cmd +)

See jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lokapujya/eb9dv192/3/

```
a {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
margin: 1em;
padding: 0.8em 1.6em;
background: linear-gradient(60deg, #005984 50%, transparent 50%) 100% 0, linear-gradient(-60deg, transparent 50%, #005984 51%) 100% 100%, linear-gradient(-90deg, transparent 1em, #005984 1em);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 1em 51%, 1em 50%, 100% 100%;
color: white;
font-family: "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 133%;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
```

}

Comment: I couldn't repro this in Safari or Firefox; different issue in Firefox (line between teal arrows)

Comment: yes, the line between the teal arrows is a another problem I'm trying to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the `background-size` seems to have done the trick.

Change line to `background-size: 1em 51%, 1em 50%, 101% 100%;`

http://jsfiddle.net/eb9dv192/5/